# How to render by HTML tag in extjs?

Tags: extjs

How to render by HTML tag in extjs?

If the project writes too many JS, it is not easy to upgrade
I want to write HTML tag in EXT.js  as possible

For example,  easyUI  (jeasyui.com)
It can be render by  HTML very friendly !

e.g

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid" title="Basic DataGrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
            data-options="singleSelect:true,collapsible:true,url:'/jeasyui/json/datagrid_data1.json',method:'get'">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-options="field:'itemid',width:80">Item ID</th>
                <th data-options="field:'productid',width:100">Product</th>
                <th data-options="field:'listprice',width:80,align:'right'">List Price</th>
                <th data-options="field:'unitcost',width:80,align:'right'">Unit Cost</th>
                <th data-options="field:'attr1',width:250">Attribute</th>
                <th data-options="field:'status',width:60,align:'center'">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

He render by "easy-xxx class" property and "data-options=json" property

How can I be like him in EXT?   (It's best not to have any JS code in htmlpage,Except for special pages)

thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. I dont understand your question. Do you wanna render this html into extjs? Or do you wanna define components like this and create extjs components? Or something else? Please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to add a grid and you want to load the data. In ExtJS you will have to create a store and load the data. For the proxy you can use `type: 'json'`. About your requirement to have as little as possible JS in your webpage: ExtJS creates single page apps and hence JS will be all over your page.

Comment: If you want to add this case to ExtJS either use a grid or add a container with HTML. The easyUI library adds to React, Vue or Angular, so that you basically use JS too. I am not sure, if you question can be answered to your satisfaction at all. A grid needs a store and the stores proxy only needs an url and a datatype. So I would say - it can be done in ExtJS, just follow the tutorials about grids on the docs page.

Comment: @光哥 maybe ExtReact will suit your needs more that Extjs